# Сортировка массива объектов по строковому свойству как по числам

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Есть массив объектов, у объектов есть строковое поле `name`, которое содержит число в строковом формате. По этому полю необходимо отсортировать массив, но сортировать не как строки, а как числа, содержащиеся в этих строках.
Вид массива:

```
0: {idStation: 0, name: "", limitUpload: null}
1: {idStation: 17, name: "1081", limitUpload: null}
2: {idStation: 18, name: "1080", limitUpload: null}
3: {idStation: 19, name: "1078", limitUpload: null}
4: {idStation: 20, name: "1079", limitUpload: null}
```

Как я это пытаюсь делать:

```js
success: function(data) {
  var dataSort = [];
  if (data != undefined) {
    dataSort = data.sort(function(a, b) {
      var a_number = a['name'];
      var b_number = b['name'];
      if (!Number.isNaN(a_number)) a_number = '0';
      if (!Number.isNaN(b_number)) b_number = '0';
      return (Number.parseInt(a_number) - Number.parseInt(b_number));
    });
  }
  DataFillingSelect(dataSort, 'idStation', 'name', '#StationId', '<option/>');
}
```

Но это не срабатывает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (/*!Number.*/isNaN(a_number)) a_number = '0';
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```